# PHP substr prevents link due to html tag

Tags: php, html, substring

I have a blog website which lists all of the latest blogs on the homepage with a photo, limited text and then a text link to the full blog post. The problem is that if I have an  tag within the blog text, it gets in the way of the blog link.

What I mean is:

If this is my blog post - "`Hello, I am wayne, writer of <a href="website.com">Bloggers Weekly</a> and this is my first article`"

And I want to abbreviate this to display 40 characters, or "Hello, I am wayne, writer of Bloggers W ... Read More"

The Read More link doesn't show up properly because in the original html there is already an `<a>` tag which prevents the second link from working. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why not use CSS to do that - [`text-overflow:ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow). Browser support is quite good.

Comment: @onetrickpony Yeah best way. But it may create problems in older IE versions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove the HTML tags before echoing the blog post.

```
echo substr(strip_tags($blog_post),0,40);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php) to remove HTML tags from the string.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the opening less than symbol before shortening the string, or lengthen the string if you want to keep the link.

```
$shortString = ($openPos = strpos($shortString, '<a')) !== false ? substr($shortString, 0 , ($openPos - 2) : substr($yourString,0,40);
```

This will cut it short just before the opening

otherwise if you want to keep the link you can use the same method and extend the short description

```
$shortString = ($closePos = strpos($yourString, '</a>')) !== false ? substr($yourString, 0 , ($closePos + 3) : substr($yourString,0,40);
```

I haven't tested this, but it should leave the link intact. Note the these will make the string less than 40 characters if the closing/opening 'a' tag comes before the first 40 characters.

The benefit to this over strip tags is that you wont leave something that should be a link in the text if you don't want it to be a link. ie.. 'Click here' text that is not clickable.

Comment: Thanks Bryan but it's a bit long winded for what I'm wanting to achieve - strip_tags seems to be working fine

Answer (score 0):

**Try this ,**

```
    $string = "Hello, I am wayne, writer of Bloggers Weekly and this is my first article";

           if (strlen($string) > 40) 
            {

                // truncate string
                $stringCut  = substr($string, 0, 40);
                $read_more = 'read more..'."<a href='website.com'>";                    
                $string     = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).$read_more;
            }

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read More link is not working properly because when you use substr, substr also inlcudes partial anchor tag. So better way is first remove tags and then apply anchor tag to Read More only.

```
<?
echo substr(strip_tags($blog),0,40) . "<a href='#link'>Read More </a>";

?>
```

Comment: B'coz my answer is little explanatory than yours. And don't vote down the answers in such manners.

Comment: But it’s not more explanatory than the accepted answer. And yes, I’ll remove my answer (even though it was the first one) because no-one gains by making SO bloated with duplicate answers.

Comment: Everyone has their own experience, and same I had, which I explain here. And you can't claim on that, as PHP is ONE, solution is ONE, just way of expression is different.